# Is there a better way to write 'do-it-yourselfer'?

Tags: punctuation

I find English punctuation wholly unsatisfactory in times like these.  I want to add an '-er' to the phrase 'do it yourself', to refer to someone who does things himself instead of hiring out the work to a professional builder, and the best I can come up with is

> do-it-yourselfer

The reason this is unsatisfactory is that, if I add parentheses to show the structure (using the parentheses the way you would in a mathematical formula) I'd come up with something like this:

> ((do it yourself)er)

Having hyphens between the words of 'do it yourself' seems fine, but then the '-er' attached directly to the word 'yourself' suggests this structure

> (do it ((yourself)er))

which is obviously wrong.

Do we have any better option than 'do-it-yourselfer'?

Comment: You're thinking too hard...don't worry about it. "Do-it-yourselfer" is just fine.

Comment: Ahh... but isn't this whole site dedicated to people who spend their time "thinking too hard" about English?

Comment: 1- I've thought long and hard, weighing all sides, judging nuances at length, and I've come to te conclusion that you shouldn't think so hard about it. 2 a also surely ther's a single sesquipedalian latinate term that captures the sense exactly, but hardly anyone has ever heard of, no one uses except in examples of weird words for everyday concepts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're right that *do-it-yourselfer* looks a bit like `(do it (yourself er))`, but in practice I don't think this is a problem.  *Do-it-yourself* is well-established as a single lexical item, and **yourselfer* is nonsense.  As a result, I think it's obvious that the suffix *-er* has scope over `(do it yourself)` and not just `(yourself)`.  (Try reading it aloud: does the spelling really change how you interpret it?)

Unfortunately, *do-it-yourself* isn't usually spelled **doityourself*, and the suffix *-er* is usually attached directly to words with no intervening hyphen, so *do-it-yourselfer* is the expected form.  However, I think there's some latitude to break the *-er* rule and insert a hyphen, so I decided to search [COCA](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/) for *do-it-yourself-er*.  Here are my search terms and the number of results for each query:

```
do-it-yourself     720
do-it-yourselfer   47
do-it-yourself-er  1
doityourself       1
doityourselfer     0
doityourself-er    0
```

(I'm not sure, but I think it's possible that the single result for *do-it-yourself-er* was the result of breaking the word across two lines, so it's possible that there were zero actual results for that search term.)

Based on the above, I think it's best to stick with *do-it-yourselfer*.  Still, if you don't mind defying convention and strongly dislike *do-it-yourselfer*, I think *do-it-yourself-er* is a credible alternative.

Comment: Have you tried DIYer or any of its variants as suggested by TrevorD?

Comment: @Mari-LouA I'm not sure what you mean by "tried", but I think TrevorD's answer is quite good.

Comment: Searching in COCA or the BNC? I was curious and... lazy :)

Comment: @Mari-LouA I see 12 results for *DIYer*, of which two are false positives (should be "dryer"), and zero for *DIY-er*.  If you'd like to do further research (such as checking other corpora), please feel free :-)

Comment: I don't like 'DIYer' because that's not what we say when we speak.  I generally like my writing to reflect (my) natural language patterns, minus hesitations, backtracking, corrections, and so forth.

Answer (score 9):

In British English, it is just as common - if not more so - to see ***DIY*** rather than ***do-it-yourself***. Consequently ***DIYer*** or ***DIY-er*** would be quite acceptable in many contexts.

Alternatively, you could rephrase it to ***someone who prefers DIY*** or something similar.

Comment: In my circle this activity is usually referred to as _BIY_ (for _Bodge-It-Yourself_).

Comment: DIY is also very common on the internet in general.  I wouldn't be surprised to see/hear it in the US.

Comment: I agree with TrevorD here - DIY and DIY-er are very acceptable.

Answer (score 6):

In Canadian English, this type of person is commonly referred to as a Handy Man, which is also a term referring to anyone whose secret weapon is duct tape.

There's really nothing wrong with "do-it-yourselfer", but I personally prefer "handy man".

**Addendum**
<3 Red Green

Comment: Welcome Jim.  Nice, direct answer.

Comment: Two words up there? Handyman is also used in the US.

Comment: I'd normally use Handyman to refer to the person you hire to do small jobs because you're not a DIYer.

Comment: @DanNeely you could hire them, but I would imagine that in their own home, they are a DIYer. Plus a handyman is more a person who fixes things or does their own home projects, etc. Someone you hire I'd call a repairman, carpenter, tradesman, etc. I can't think of a situation where a handyman isn't a DIYer and a DIYer isn't handy

Comment: I'm saying I'd normally only use it to describe people who're hiring out; not someone who just does his own stuff at home and occasionally helps a friend for a few beers.

Comment: @DanNeely I'm with Dan on this. In BrE, I would say that *Handyman* is generally used for someone who you hire to do work for you. Obviously he would also do work on his own home! But I would say that a DIYer is someone who does work on his own home, but does **not** do paid work for others.

Comment: @Jim I don't understand your **Addendum**. What does *<3 Red-Green* mean?

Comment: @TrevorD perhaps it's a cultural usage difference, but the way we use it is that a handyman is someone who fixes up things around their own place and occasionally helps a friend build a new deck or something for beers. Some handymen are also hired, but it isn't related. Also, you'd have to be Canadian to understand the addendum. Red Green is a person and the exemplar of a handyman.

Comment: I suppose American and British vs Canadian makes an interesting change from the standard American vs British comment threads...

Comment: @DanNeely Indeed, my brother is (now) Canadian (born & married (to a Canadian) in UK), and speaks an 'interesting' mix of American and the English spoken in "God's own country"!

Comment: A handyman is (to my mind) necessarily skilled ("handy") at what he does, while a do-it-yourselfer (*I feel I'm committing a punctuational sin writing it that way*) is not, and could easily bungle things badly.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say "a do-it-yourself enthusiast". or a diy enthusiast.

Comment: Hi Sandra.  Thanks very much for your answer, and welcome to the site!  Please consider adding some explanation or a citation and source to help expand on your answer.